# VBA Runtime Error 1004 Application-defined or Object-defined error

Tags: vba, excel

Hello I am kind of new in VB and I am trying to copy data from one sheet of a workbook to another sheet of another workbook, but when I try to do so I receive the error that says:

> "Error 1004: Application-defined or Object-defined Error"

The same code has given the required output but it doesn't function every time.

Search data for user selection of date in `Working` worksheet of file `Weather Dashboard` in `Master` File `Sheet1` and paste in the `Weather Dashboard`.

The master file contains 200000 rows of data, and  total data to be copied will be around 1000 rows.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Windows("Weather Dashboard.xlsm").Activate
    stra = Worksheets("Working").Cells(1, 1)

    'stores user input date as integer in stra
    Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Users\Desktop\Master.xlsx"
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Select
    a = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For j = 0 To 9
        For i = 2 To a
            'Search for the chosen date & following 9 days from Master File
            If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 5).Value = stra + j Then
                Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(i).Copy
                Windows("Weather Dashboard.xlsm").Activate
                b = Worksheets("Working").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
                Worksheets("Working").Cells(b + 1, 1).Select

                ActiveSheet.Paste

                Windows("Master.xlsx").Activate
                Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
            End If
        Next i
    Next j
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Comment: For each date, there would be 96 rows of data hence the i iteration.

Comment: Upon which line does it throw the error?

Comment: it is showing error after opening the file itself.

Comment: I see a `.copy`. Does this code every paste the data it copies? It seems like it's a really bulky piece of code that just finds a range, copies it, and then that's it.

Comment: starting of For loop (j)

Comment: yes, it copies the data where it gets a match.

Comment: But there isn't any `.paste` line. Was the `Worksheets("Working").Cells(b + 1, 1).Select` changed to be `.Select` instead of `.paste` at some point? I think it's unrelated to the problem you are having, but I was wanting to understand the code in hopes I could spot the issue you are facing.

Comment: My first suggestion would be to add a line at the top of [every] module [always]: **`Option Explicit`** which will help "force" you to properly declare and handle your variables, objects, properties, etc.

Comment: How to find the range? 
Eg: There will be 90 rows for 1 day & i need data for day 20th april to 28th april. How to change the code for that?
I have tried iteration, but in that also i am getting the same error "Object Defined error"

Comment: Paste function will be after the select function. Please check the edited question

Comment: Based on user selection of a date say 20th april, The code needs to search all rows containing 20th april one by one from master & copy to the Weather Dashboard file (96 rows will be matching & they need to be copied & pasted).
This needs to be repeated for 9 following days.

Comment: Why not use `AutoFilter` to filter out the needed date range to copy and then copy the visible cells in the filtered range. More efficient than looping.

Comment: @Antip Get rid of `Select` & `Activate` and fully qualify your ranges (i.e. `Rows.Count`).

Answer (score 0):

I'm just rewriting to remove implicit references here: not solving any other issues

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
dim a as long
dim b as long
Dim Stra as integer
dim wbDash as workbook
set wbDash =  workbooks("Weather Dashboard.xlsm")   
stra =wbdash.Worksheets("Working").Cells(1, 1)
dim wb as workbook
'stores user input date as integer in stra
set wb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Desktop\Master.xlsx")
with wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    a = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For j = 0 To 9
        For i = 2 To a
            'Search for the chosen date & following 9 days from Master File
            If .Cells(i, 5).Value = stra + j Then
                 b = wbdash.Worksheets("Working").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
               .Rows(i).Copy _
                  destination:=
                wbdash.Worksheets("Working").Cells(b + 1, 1)


            End If
        Next i
    Next j
end with   
End Sub
```

I think this will get rid of your error

Comment: can you just write the code again for the loop..the one which you have written is showing some syntax error..

Comment: b = wbdash.Worksheets("Working").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
               .Rows(i).Copy _
                  destination:=
                wbdash.Worksheets("Working").Cells(b + 1, 1)

Comment: It is showing error "runtime error 6 overflow" even after making iteration parameter i as Long. Kindly suggest!

Comment: what should stra be? it's set as integer but might need to be long?

Comment: stra is basically to store date value in integer.. it could be set as long

Comment: dates are longs (Technically doubles if they hold the time as well). Today's date is 43,223, and max integer is 32,767